# Recover files from Web Deploy "Remove additional files at destination"

Tags: windows-server-2012, webdeploy

I've deployed a website on a dedicated OVH server running Windows Server 2012.
I used WebDeploy and I checked the option "Remove additional files at destination". A WordPress folder was at this destination and was deleted.

How may I recover those files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your out of luck.  There isn't any way to recover the files via WebDeploy.

Maybe you can recover the files using one of those undelete utilities that does a deep scan of the harddrive to attempt to recover files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm currently scanning the hard drive with Recuva.

Comment: If this answer was helpful please mark it as the answer and/or vote it up.  Thanks!